# How to implement tidyr's complete() in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, oracle, tidyr

Using a dummy example, I need to complete a data set with implicit missing values. This is trivial in `R` using `tidyr`'s function `complete`.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Borough = c('Brooklyn', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens'),
                 Crime = c('Robbery', 'Homicide', 'Drug'),
                 Count=c(1, 2, 1))

> df
   Borough    Crime Count
1 Brooklyn  Robbery     1
2 Brooklyn Homicide     2
3   Queens     Drug     1

#Complete implicit missing values

> complete(df, Borough, Crime, fill=list(Count=0))
   Borough    Crime Count
1 Brooklyn     Drug     0
2 Brooklyn Homicide     2
3 Brooklyn  Robbery     1
4   Queens     Drug     1
5   Queens Homicide     0
6   Queens  Robbery     0
```

But, in the case that the real data very big and is stored in Oracle's SQL table, how could this be done using an SQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cross join distinct boroughs with crimes and left join the original table to get the missing rows with 0 counts.

```
select b.borough,c.crime,coalesce(t.count,0) as count
from (select distinct borough from tbl) b
cross join (select distinct crime from tbl) c
left join tbl t on t.borough=b.borough and t.crime=c.crime
```